# Degradation of 4-MeO-Tetrahydrocarbazole

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, heterocyclic-compounds

I recently synthesized 4-Methoxy-Tetrahydroxarbazole from 4-MeO-Phenylhydrazine and Cyclohexanone. The product had a off-white color directly after synthesis but was brown after standing over night at room temperature. I could not find any informations on the sensitivity of the compound toward oxidation or on its stability in general.

Also, other people in our lab reported that their product degraded during column chromatography.

Does anybody have experience with this compound and has also made these observations?

Comment: Have you named this material correctly? 4-methoxy-phenylhydrazine + cyclohexanone gives 6-methoxy-tetrahydrocarbazole as reported here  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358021573_A_review_on_synthesis_methods_of_tricyclic_1234-tetrahydrocarbazoles  The references documented in this review may prove useful.

Comment: particularly this reference  Synthetic Communications®. 16 Dec 2008; 39(1): 158-65.

Comment: You should first correct your question according to comments of Waylander (above). For your info, these chemicals are susceptible to react woth atmospheric oxygen (as most amines do). For example, see an oxydation process reported in [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4203109/).